# iterate over non-const std::unordered_set

Tags: c++11, iterator, constants, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have a `std::unordered_set` that contains instances of class `bar`.

I'd like to iterate over all the `bar`s in the set and call some `void foo(bar& b)` function on each one.

You'll probably notice from the function signature that I want `foo` to change the state of the `bar& b` parameter in some way.

Now, I do know that `foo` won't change `bar` in a way that affects hashing or equality comparisons, but I still have a problem.

However I iterate over the set, the best I can hope for is a `const bar&` which obviously won't work.

I can think of a couple of possible ways around this:

1. Use `const_cast`. Don't know if this will work *(yet)*. It kind of smells bad to me, but I'm happy to be enlightened!!
2. Use a `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_set`, so that even if I can only get a `const` of the key, I can just use that key to lookup the `bar` object and safely call `foo` on it.

I'd really appreciate some advice!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some clean solutions have already been shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44724784/7571258).

Another clean way would be to add a layer of indirection through a pointer. Even if the pointer itself is `const`, the data *pointed to* will not be:

```
struct Bar
{
    int key;
    std::unique_ptr<int> pValue;
};

std::unordered_set< Bar, BarHash, BarEqual > bars;

for( const auto& bar : bars )
{
    // Works because only the pointer is constant, not the data pointed to.
    *bar.pValue = 42;
}
```

This obviously has the overhead of an additional memory allocation, the space required to store the pointer and the indirection when accessing the value through the pointer.

You will also have to write a custom copy constructor and an assignment operator if you want to keep *value semantics*.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `const_cast`. Don't know if this will work (yet). It kind of smells bad to me, but I'm happy to be enlightened!!

Yes, it will work. You can easily have an overload `foo(bar const&)`, `const_cast` the reference, and then call `foo(bar&)`. I agree with you that it smells bad and points to a flaw in design. You might want to take a fresh look at the design and see if there is a clean solution.

> Use a `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_set`, so that even if I can only get a const of the key, I can just use that key to lookup the bar object and safely call foo on it

That is not too different from the first approach. `std::unordered_set<T>` is essentially `std::unordered_map<T, bool>`.

Potential clean solutions:

1. Get a copy of the object from the set, remove the entry from the set, update the copy, and put the copy back in the set. If that proves too expensive ...
2. Use a `std::vector<Bar>`. You can get a `Bar&` from the vector and all is well.
3. Make the member variables of `Bar` that don't impact its hash value to be `mutable`. Then, you can just use `foo(Bar const&)` and be able to call it directly using a reference to the objects in the set.

Comment: It should be noted that `mutable` only works for simple structs. If you have a class with private members that can only be accessed through non-const setters, you'd still need a `const_cast`.

Comment: `const_cast` is undefined behavior if the `unordered_set` keeps `const` pointers to objects that were declared `const`.

Comment: @jbapple, the OP is not storing pointers to `const` objects in the `unordered_set`. They are storing objects.

Comment: `unordered_set` commonly stores pointers to objects. It would be standard-compliant to allocate a new const object on every `insert` and then store a pointer to it in a hash table. That pointer would then be a `const T *` since the object would be a `const T`, so `const_cast` would be UB.

Comment: Interesting point about the unordered_set being an unordered_map with a bool value! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a structure like this:

```
struct Bar
{
    int key;
    int value;
}
```

If you're confident that the `value` parameter won't be used in the calculation of the object's hash value, you can mark the `value` as `mutable`. This annotation allows you to modify the `value` parameter of the `Bar` structure even when you have a `const` instance of `Bar`.

```
struct Bar
{
    int key;
    mutable int value;
}
```

Although, it should be used judiciously to avoid unintended side effects.